# Bootstrap : animation in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

i want to use wow.js animations (with animate.css) in a modal window of bootstrap like this

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInLeft">
                   <p>Animation from Right</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInRight">
                   <p>Animation from Right</p>
                </div>
             </div> 
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

i included wow.js, animate.css , animations are working properly in the page but in modal window it does not work , Need your help with this please

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because when you call `wow.init()`, the lightbox element doesn't exist yet.

You need to call either `wow.init()` or `wow.sync()` after the element is created (i.e. when it is opened) in order for the wow code to find the element.

Bootstrap can run a callback when the modal is created and shown.  Yours will end up looking something like this

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  wow.sync()
})
```